# pass multiple checkboxes' values to the textbox

Tags: javascript

I need Java script to  pass multiple checkboxes' values to the textbox?

For example:
If I check two checkboxes then I see the textbox shows two checkboxes' values separated by a comma like "coffee,beer".when I uncheck the checked  checkboxes,  that particular value alone should dissappear from the textbox.

```
       <form name="form1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="coffee">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="tea">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="beer">

         </form>

          <form name="form2">
          <input type="text" name="textname">
              </form>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: No, I Tried with many methods couldn get the expected thing can you able to develop a java script for the above codin

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ggxqn/

```
$("form[name=form1]").on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    var values = $.map($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function(el) {
        return el.value;
    });
    $("form[name=form2]").find("input[name=textname]").val(values); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class="click_checkbox" in every check boxes and id="textname" in the input type text.

And then add this jquery in your page.

```
$(".click_checkbox").live('click',function(){   
    var checkbox_value=$(this).val();
    if($("#textname").val()=="")
   {
    var str=$("#textname").val()+checkbox_value;
   }
    else
    {
    var str=$("#textname").val()+","+checkbox_value;
    }       
    $("#textname").val(str);
});
```

Just include jquery.js. Hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my solution is not that elegant.

```
var textbox = document.getElementsByName("textname")[0];
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("checkboxname");
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = (function(chk){
        return function() {
            var value = "";
            for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                if (checkboxes[j].checked) {
                    if (value === "") {
                        value += checkboxes[j].value;
                    } else {
                        value += "," + checkboxes[j].value;
                    }
                }
            }
            textbox.value = value;
        }
    })(checkbox);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3hvyr/)
Hope it also helps you.